# How do we merge multiple plots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

We want to annotate plots after we fit the model using `RandomForestRegressor` and plot the actual and predicted values. The two datasets we are considering are found in the following link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ak8jGD1OxTT0bXM4TkdTeDQ

However if i combine the two datasets as

`df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "testdata*.csv"))))`

and apply the plot commands, the plots are merged two as we can see in the following plots.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the the coordinates of the text too, e.g. `xytext=(-30,30)`.
You might then determine the coordinates to annotate from your data. I can't be sure if this is working (as there is no reproducible example in the question) but would suggest to try something like

```
plt.annotate('annote test!', 
             xy=(len(modelPred_test), modelPred_test[-1]),  
             xycoords='data',
             xytext=(-30,30),
             textcoords='offset points',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
```